# Make new line of text in the same message that aligns with the very left?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I've been having extreme difficulty with figuring out how to either make a new line of text in the same comment and how to make them line up with each other on the left "wall" of the comment. Maybe the answer is obvious and I just need another set of eyes.

```
public async void PrintInfo()
    {
        string info =
            "**Stats:**" + "".PadRight(93) +
            behindWholeStat[0] + " = " + wholeStats[0] + "".PadRight((int)(90 - Math.Floor(Math.Log10(wholeStats[0]) + 1)))
            + behindWholeStat[1] + " = " + wholeStats[1] + "".PadRight((int)(90 - Math.Floor(Math.Log10(wholeStats[1]) + 1)))
            + behindWholeStat[2] + " = " + wholeStats[2] + "".PadRight((int)(90 - Math.Floor(Math.Log10(wholeStats[2]) + 1)))
            + behindWholeStat[3] + " = " + wholeStats[3] + "".PadRight((int)(90 - Math.Floor(Math.Log10(wholeStats[3]) + 1)))
            + behindWholeStat[4] + " = " + wholeStats[4] + "".PadRight((int)(90 - Math.Floor(Math.Log10(wholeStats[4]) + 1)))
            + behindWholeStat[5] + " = " + wholeStats[5] + "".PadRight((int)(90 - Math.Floor(Math.Log10(wholeStats[5]) + 1)))
            + "**Race:** " + rasr.chossenRace + ", **Subrace:** " + rasr.chossenSubrace + "".PadRight(83 - (rasr.chossenRace.Length + rasr.chossenSubrace.Length))
            + "**Class:** " + casc.chossenClass + ", **Subclass:** " + casc.chossenSubclass + "".PadRight(81 - (casc.chossenClass.Length + casc.chossenSubclass.Length))
            + "**Alignment:** " + chossenAlignment + "".PadRight(85 - (chossenAlignment.Length));

        await ReplyAsync(info);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure but I think what you are looking for is `"\n"`

You can insert line breaks in a string with `\n`

```cs
"This will be in first line\nThis will be in second line\nAnd this will be in third"
```

Output:

This will be in first line
This will be in second line
And this will be in third